# How can I find a Java class that's "already defined in an unnamed package"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

I'm trying to convert a `FlowLayout()` UI to a `GridBagLayout()` UI. After a few modification and tests, I started getting a compiler error:

```
*classname* is already defined in unnamed package
```

and I decided to roll back to the `FlowLayout()` version--my last working version. That version compiles fine, but when I run (from the command line), my messed up `GridBagLayout()` is displayed.

I tried renaming the .java file, but I get the compiler error noted above. I restarted my console window and notepad, in case something was stuck in memory somewhere. That did not fix the problem.

However, I did take the `FlowLayout()` version to a laptop on which I hadn't compiled the `GridBagLayout()` changes. On that machine, it ran just fine, giving me the `FlowLayout()` I was expecting.

I've scanned my /java directory for *.class, deleted all the classes I found, but I still get the error. I'm running Win7 if it makes a difference. Notepad is my "IDE" and I'm running everything from the command prompt.

What do I need to look for to flush this "unnamed package"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the link posted by @esseks to understand about Java packages. I'm posting just to help you find any duplicate class definitions fast by using `findstr` (Windows equivalent of `grep`)

```
C:\> CD C:\path\to\java

// delete all .class files
C:\path\to\java>del /S *.class

// find all .java files with FlowLayout class definition
C:\path\to\java>findstr /S /I /N /C:"class flowlayout" *.java

// find all .java files with GridBagLayout class definition
C:\path\to\java>findstr /S /I /N /C:"class gridbaglayout" *.java
```

*Legend:*

- /S = Recurse sub-directories
- /I = Case-insensitive match
- /N = Print line numbers
- /C = String to find in the files

Answer (score 2):

All of your files without a leading `package` statement. Anyway, as reported in [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html):

> Generally speaking, an unnamed package is only for small or temporary applications or when you are just beginning the development process. Otherwise, classes and interfaces belong in named packages.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but none of my files have a leading package statement. I've got a couple `import`s, then `public class foo`

Comment: Ok, then you are defining a class with the same name in two source files of your project. Refer to the doc page I linked above for a quick explanation of packages.